# How can i make a calculator with string that uses multiple operations and brackets? C#

Tags: c#, string, calculator

My calculator works almost perfect without brackets (it has some bugs). This calculator can do multiple operations (ex. 12+345*2-100  //602).
I want the brackets and the string inside them to be replaced with the result in and then continue with the calculations.
 How can i fix the method for the brackets so it works as intended?

Steps for calculations:

1. Finds an symbol
2. Finds the numbers around the symbol
3. Makes calculations and replaces numbers and symbol with the result in the string
4. Checks for any symbols and starts again if there are any
5. Gives the result of the mathematical problem

   ```
   //Finds numbers around an symbol
   static void FindNumbers(string equation, int start, char symbol)
   {
       number1 = 0;
       number2 = 0;
       number1String = string.Empty;
       number2String = string.Empty;

       if (equation[start] == symbol)
       {
           for (int j = start - 1; j >= 0; j--)//Finds left number around the symbol
           {
               if (char.IsDigit(equation[j]))
               {
                   number1String = equation[j] + number1String;
               }
               else
               {
                   break;
               }
           }
           for (int j = start + 1; j < equation.Length; j++)//Finds right number around the symbol
           {
               if (char.IsDigit(equation[j]))
               {
                   number2String += equation[j];
               }
               else
               {
                   break;
               }
           }
           number1 = int.Parse(number1String);
           number2 = int.Parse(number2String);
       }
       return;
   }

   //Devision and Multiplication
   static void Priority1(string equation, int start)
   {
       for (int i = start; i < equation.Length; i++)//Multiplication
       {
           if (equation[i] == '*')
           {
               symbol = equation[i];
               FindNumbers(equation, i, symbol);

               currentresult = number1 * number2;

               equation = equation.Replace(number1.ToString() + symbol + number2.ToString(),
                   currentresult.ToString());
           }
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < equation.Length; i++)//Devision
       {
           if (equation[i] == '/')
           {
               symbol = equation[i];
               FindNumbers(equation, i, symbol);

               currentresult = number1 / number2;

               equation = equation.Replace(number1.ToString() + symbol + number2.ToString(),
                   currentresult.ToString());
           }
       }
       Priority2(equation, 0);
   }

   //Addition and Devision
   static void Priority2(string equation, int start)
   {
       for (int i = start; i < equation.Length; i++)//Addition
       {
           if (equation[i] == '+')
           {
               symbol = equation[i];
               FindNumbers(equation, i, symbol);

               currentresult = number1 + number2;

               equation = equation.Replace(number1.ToString() + symbol + number2.ToString(),
                   currentresult.ToString());
           }
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < equation.Length; i++)//Devision
       {
           if (equation[i] == '-')
           {
               symbol = equation[i];
               FindNumbers(equation, i, symbol);

               currentresult = number1 - number2;

               equation = equation.Replace(number1.ToString() + symbol + number2.ToString(),
                   currentresult.ToString());
           }
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < equation.Length; i++)//Checks if there are more symbols in the string
       {
           if (char.IsSymbol(equation[i]))
           {
               Priority1(equation, 0);
           }
       }
       tempresult = equation;
       Console.WriteLine("Result : " + equation);
   }

   //Brackets
   static void Brackets(string equation, int index)
   {
       for (int i = index; index < equation.Length; index++)
       {
           if (equation[index] == '(')
           {
               index += 1;
               Brackets(equation, index);

               for (int j = index; j < equation.Length; j++)
               {
                   if (equation[j] == ')')
                   {
                       tempresult = temp;
                       Console.WriteLine("..." + tempresult);
                       break;
                   }
                   temp += equation[j];
               }

               Priority1(tempresult, index);
               equation = equation.Replace('(' + temp.ToString() + ')', tempresult.ToString());
               Console.WriteLine("." + equation);
           }
       }
       Priority1(equation, 0);
   }

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       equation = Console.ReadLine();

       Brackets(equation, 0);
       Console.ReadKey();
   }
   ```

Comment: Step 0: Define your expression syntax

Comment: this smells like homework! And also something I would attempt as a TDD Kata

Comment: Actualy this is not homework, but i found something in a book and this came to my mind, so i decided to try to make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code right now theoretically knows how to parse and evaluate correct simple mathematical expressions. By simple expressions I’m referring to expressions made up only of known unary and binary operators and numbers (no parenthesizes)

The expression you are now attempting to parse is either:

1. A simple expression
2. A parenthesized expression
3. A complex expression made up of simple expressions and  parenthesized expressions

If its case #1, then you already know how to handle it; parse it and you are finished.

If it’s case #2 the simply remove the parenthesis and parse the expression within.

If it’s case #3 then you take the expressions inside the top level parenthesizes and parse them; you will either be in step 1 or 2 or 3 and hey! Guess what? You already know how to handle those.

Eventually you’ll end up breaking down your expression into only simple expressions. Then you simply need to backtrack evaluating on the way back.

In plain English, you need a recursive parser; a parser that can call itself and parse and evaluate nested expressions.

Consider for example:

```
e0: 1 + (2 * (3 - 2))
```

1. e0: You parse `1 + p0`
2. p0: You parse `2 * p1`
3. p1: You parse `3 - 2`
4. You’re done parsing
5. p1: evaluates to `1`
6. p0: evaluates to `2`
7. e0: evaluates to `3`
8. You’re finished.

Cool thing about this is that the parser can handle, theoretically, infinite nested expressions... the problem is that your computer probably can’t.

Comment: You don't really need a recursive-descent parser for this type of thing. It's a valid approach, but algorithms like Shunting-Yard are simpler and faster.

Comment: @3Dave I know, just pointing out alternative approaches. It’s very instructive to write your own parser.

Comment: Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look into breaking the String equation into separate tokens and use something like the [Shunting-Yard-Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to parse/calculate the result.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.